# How can I upload a picture using Glide from an external folder

Tags: android, file-upload, android-glide

I am developing an app for my auntie: the app displays recipes in a card view inside a Recycler view, the data comes from an SQLite DB.

The images at the moment are just static inside @drawable/... I have read the "@drawable" folder is compiled into the apk and not accessible after the fact. Consequently the need to store the images externally.

The DB stores the filenames.

The card displays basic info, when a card is clicked it opens another activity that displays full information.

Everything works perfectly **EXCEPT**

I obviously want her to be able to upload pictures and add info, the pictures will be stored in: "/sdcard/Pictures/Recipes/"

In am using Glide as recommended, however Glide reports the following error:

```
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/sdcard/Pictures/Recipes/carrot_cake.jpg: open failed: EFAULT (Bad address))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: EFAULT (Bad address))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: EFAULT (Bad address))...
```

If I use the following code:

```
    String image = "/sdcard/Pictures/Recipes/carrot_cake.jpg"; // hard coded for example
    File file = new File( image );
    if( file.exists() && file.canRead() )
    {
        Log.d( TAG, "File exists" );
        Glide.with( context ).load( image ).into( foodImage ); // foodImage = ImageView
    }
```

The log displays the "File Exists", however, Glide won't load and reports the aforementioned error.

Comment: use this `String image = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pictures/Recipes/carrot_cake.jpg";` as path

Comment: @Knight Fighter, Deprecated since API 29, thanks, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(directory, "Pictures/Recipes/carrot_cake.jpg");

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/Recipes/carrot_cake.jpg";
if( file.exists() && file.canRead() ) {
    Log.d( TAG, "File exists" );
    Glide.with( context ).load( new File(path)).into( foodImage ); // foodImage = ImageView
}
```

Comment: Thanks @knight-fighter **AND** others, however I should have mentioned, I have tried **ALL** of these and a many other suggestions, none seem to work. P.S **Priyank-py** you need to do File file = new File( ... ) before testing for existence ;)

Answer (score 0):

After much research and head beating 
The following code is extensively modified for brevity and simplicity, obviously the reading of files would go into a custom object and the adapter for the recycle view updated.

```
File folder = new File( getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES ) + IMAGE_DIR );  // where IMAGE_DIR is the folder you want to save or retrieve files from
File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
String fileName = fileList[0].getPath();
Glide.with( context ).load( fileName ).into( imageView );
```

**Note** getExternalStorageDirectory() et al. are all deprecated as of API 29

**Also**, you need to add permissions, but that's another story.